# C, salary commissions

Tags: c

Yes, this is homework:

> One chemical company pays its sales people on a commission basis.  The
>   sales people receive $200/ week plus 9% of their gross sales for that
>   week.  For example, a sales person who sells $5,000.00  worth of
>   chemicals will receive $200 plus the 9% of $5,000 for a total of $650.
>
> Develop a program that will input a sales person gross sales an will
>   calculate and display that person's earnings.
>
> Example of an output:
>
> ```
> Salary is : $650.00
> ```
>
> Be sure that in your program you consider the following:
>
> Your program includes:
>
> 1. proper case, variable names(meaningful and use conventions)
> 2. proper organization, indentation, white space, and comments
> 3. Has the right inputs and outputs, computes correct results, is efficient

My artwork;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    const double commission = 0.09;
    double gross_sales, salary;

    printf("Enter amount of gross sales\n");
    scanf("%.03d", &gross_sales);

    printf("Your salary for this week: %.03d\n", &salary);
    scanf("salary = gross_sales*commission + 200 %.03d", &salary);

    system("pause");   
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to do — can you help?

Comment: We don't need all that background info as it is not relevant to the problem. What we do need is a clear question. "can any one explain to me where I messed up ". That's not how it works. You tell us how the program isn't working as you expect and we help you identify the problem.

Comment: `scanf("%.03d", &gross_sales);`. That's one of your problems. `%d` is for `int` not `double`. Use `%lf` for `double`.

Comment: And not very far to the next problem: `printf("Your salary for this week: %.03d\n", &salary);`. Firstly, `salary` is an uninitalised variable so printing it will give random garbage. Secondly, `printf` does not take a pointer to the values so should be just `salary` not `&salary`.

Comment: You solved my problem by pointing out the 'random garbage', sorry for not clarifying my problem earlier as I was sure that it was a number of things.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
scanf("%.03d", &gross_sales); // gross_sales is double
```

`d` specifier is meant for integers. It should be `lf` for `double`

For printing the content of a variable you need not prefix the `address of` operator, so

```
printf("Your salary for this week: %.03d\n", &salary);
```

is wrong and it should have been

```
printf("Your salary for this week: %.03lf\n", salary);
```

But then, you might have realized by now that there is no need to print the salary at this point because you haven't read the variable yet. In fact the standard (6.7.9->10) says :

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate

`scanf` at the end requires same modification as mentioned in the first point.